# How to run Browser command using jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, dom-events

I have one page in HTML , there are two buttons , save and print.

When user click on the Print it should print the page and
When user click on the Save page it should Open Save as... Box for that page.

Javascript/jQuery solution preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing you can use `window.print()`.

There is no standard way to trigger the Save dialog. In IE you can use `document.execCommand('SaveAs')`.

**EDIT**: Technically `window.print` isn't part of any standard (Source: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.print)) but it's widely available.

Answer (score 1):

try: (this is just for "save as") ripped and edited from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1476631&page=1)

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#save').click(function() {
        if (!!window.ActiveXObject) {
            document.execCommand("SaveAs");
        } else if (!!window.netscape) {
            var r=document.createRange();
            r.setStartBefore($("head")[0]);
            var oscript=r.createContextualFragment('<script id="scriptid" type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/contentAreaUtils.js"><\/script>');
            $('body').append(oscript);
            r=null;
            try {
                netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
                saveDocument(document);
            } catch (e) {
                //no further notice as user explicitly denied the privilege
            } finally {
                //re-defined
               $("#scriptid").remove();
            }
        }
   return false;
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="save">save the document</a>
</body>
</html>
```