# javascript save as met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save a HTML page in Firefox using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777000/save-a-html-page-in-firefox-using-javascript)

Can anyone suggest a method to invoke "Save as" dialogue to save a webpage locally using JavaScript method? I have tried `document.execCommand()` which works fine with IE but not in other browsers. I cannot use PHP or anything else.

Comment: you can do it only in IE, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777000/save-a-html-page-in-firefox-using-javascript) question

Comment: You may have some luck with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2145724/485418